# Blade directives aren't working, code keeps showing in the browser instead of executing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

My blade directives aren't working, as you see I don't have the PHP code in PHP tags, because its a blade directive and I'm not supposed to add those. But for some reason the PHP code keeps showing in the browser and not executing, why is this happening?

Also, in my text editor, the PHP code color is white, which I can tell is a problem. I think that the code is outdated, and if so, how can I get it up to date?

I'm using Laravel 5.5, and my PHP version is 7.0.

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="post" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
        <a href="#"><h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3></a>
        <h6>Posted on {{ $post->created_at }} by {{ $post->user->name }}</h6>
        <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
        <div class="interaction">
            <a href="#">Likes</a>
            <a href="#">Dislikes</a>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What version of laravel you are using?

Comment: @Tithira I'm using Version 5.5, and my PHP version is 7.0

Comment: Isyour `something.blade.php` file named correctly?

Comment: If native php script doesn't work then something to do with laravel.Have you double checked the blade templates in .blade.php format?

Comment: How are you loading the blade template?

Comment: @Pablo What do you mean by blade template? I started learning Laravel 2 days ago so I need help with understanding the correct language.

Comment: @Deskie you are saving the sample code in a `.blade.php` file. Please show the statement that you are using to load such file.

Answer (score 1):

Blade view files use the  `.blade.php` file extension...So your file MUST be `something.blade.php` otherwise, blade syntax will not be recognized...Double check your file name.

About the code color ... Which editor do you use?

**Sublime text 3** - PHP code and BLADE syntax are white.

**VScode** - PHP code and BLADE syntax are white.

**Atom** - PHP code and BLADE syntax are light gray.

Answer (score 0):

Your file must have .blade extension in it, otherwise @, {{ }} etc would not be recognize, and would not work.
Check if your files are named correctly like example.blade.php